# How to disable/enable an action set in Eclipse e4?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-kepler

I am writing a plug-in for Eclipse Kepler that is aimed to read some data from the debugger. Currently, the action set with the Resume, Step into, etc. buttons is enabled. If a user clicks, for example, the Resume Button, the thread that reads from the debugger will of course fail.

Is there any way to disable/enable an action set from the Java code in Eclipse Kepler knowing the action set ID?

Comment: Is this really an 'e4' application, are you defining the application model in an `application.e4xmi` file? It sounds more like a Eclipse 3.x compatible application.

Comment: Not really an E4 app. It is a plug-in for Eclipse Kepler. However, Eclipse 3.x had a method WorkbenchPage.findPerspective(IPerspectiveDescriptor desc), which is now gone.

Comment: `WorkbenchPage` is an internal class and so is not part of the API and should not be used. As you have found it is subject the change without notice.

Answer (score 0):

Your action implementation of `IWorkbenchWindowActionDelegate` can also implement `IActionDelegate2`, among other things this gives you the method

```
public void init(IAction action)
```

giving you access to the main `IAction`. You then call `IAction.setEnabled(boolean)` to change the action enablement.

Comment: I appreciate your help, however I am not the owner of the action delegates implementation (these are from the standard Eclipse debugger plug-in), so everything I have at the moment is the ID of the `ActionSet` and the IDs of the single actions.

Comment: Well the debug plugin Resume action is `org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.commands.actions.ResumeCommandActionDelegate` this has elaborate mechanisms for enabling the action and it is not clear that you can hook in to them.

Comment: Just FYI, since you have been quite involved in looking for a solution. I have not found any way to disable an action from another plug-in. I ended up with just handling the exception risen when trying to read from the debugger in the running state.